# Angularjs handling leaving a template in various ways?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django

I am trying to implement a function in my angular module that will fire an event that saves the changes on the page. The different ways a user can leave the page is:

1. Clicking a link that loads a new template.
2. Clicking the back button
3. Closing the tab/window

My implementation handles #1 using this code:

```
.directive('confirmOnExit', function() {
    return {
        link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
            window.onbeforeunload = function(){
                    return "If you leave this page, you will exit the practice session. You will be able to view your score report for the completed session but will have to start a new one if you want to continue practicing.";
            }
            $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
                    if($scope.$dirty & confirm("Are you sure you want to leave this practice session?")) {
                        console.log("Will end session!");
                        end_session();
                    }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

However, when #2 or #3 occur, the pop up dialog shows up but it seems like it is not triggering the **`end_session()`** function.

Any insights into how to deal with the back button and closing the tab/window would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like a race condition. end_session() might not be firing before the browser successfully unloads the page, but without more code I can't really help, since I'm not sure what end_session() does.

What you *could* do is capture the locationChangeStart and defer it until after all of your unload tasks are complete.

A quick note, directly referencing window is an Angular "anti-pattern" of sorts:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window